# How do natural language categories determine if a capsule knows about a news topic?

Tags: bixby

How does Bixby's natural language categories service https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/categories know whether a capsule subscribed to the news category knows anything about a topic of a news query like "Find me today’s news headlines in business"?  A news capsule might have excellent coverage on several topics but thin coverage on another. Ideally, the routing service would be aware of these variations. Does Bixby look at the capsule metadata?  Also, is there a canonical list of news topics?

This is important for me as I have a news service with sparse but rapidly growing coverage and I need to know how to communicate that accurately for best customer experience.

Answer (score 1):

The natural language system won't know if your capsule doesn't support a feature.

If your news service is sparse, then you should return a sensible error for the user, or otherwise communicate that your capsule isn't for that type of news.

For example, take a look at the "My Japanese Dictionary" capsule - it's part of the "Translators" category, but clearly, it only handles Japanese. I think it's pretty obvious that this capsule won't support other languages. Is this case, it's up to the users to be intelligent about what capsules they choose to enable/mark as preferred.